# Bootstrap 4 Accordion ScrollTop

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, scrolltop

I'm on this for straight two hours and can't figure it out. 
I have a website, which has a container and inside this container is a Bootstrap standard accordion. Some text parts are pretty long so I thought it might be useful is the title of the accordion card scrolls to the top.

I found some scripts here and on GitHub but I can't figure out how to scroll only the content of the container to the top.

Here is the jQuery code snippet:

```
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {

    var karte = $(this).closest('.card');
    $('.info').animate({
        scrollTop: karte.offset().top
    }, 2000);

});
```

I put up a fiddle with a demo site:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/271473/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve your problem we have to do 2 things:

1. Change jquery library with a not slim version 'cause we need animate function.
2. We need to know .card position relative to its parent (.info) not to document. To get this we have to use position, not offset. https://api.jquery.com/position/ For more exact scrolling position, we have to add also `.info` padding-top (i.e. 140px in your case).

With those changes your jquery become this:

```
    $(function() {
      var padding = parseInt($('.info').css("padding-top"), 10);

      /* limit this event only to .collapse in .info */
      $('.info .collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {

          var karte = $(this).closest('.card');

          $('.info').animate({
              scrollTop: karte.position().top + padding
          }, 2000);

      });
    });
```

This is the result (remember to change jQuery library) *[I removed some cards 'cause in SO there is a limit of characters]*:

```js
$(function() {
  var padding = parseInt($('.info').css("padding-top"), 10);

  $('.info .collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {

      var karte = $(this).closest('.card');
      
      $('.info').animate({
          scrollTop: karte.position().top + padding
      }, 2000);

  });
});
```

```css
.info {
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: visible;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  max-height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 140px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   <section class="navigation-mobile">
        TOP PART
      </section>

    <div class="content orange container-fluid animated fadeInRight wide">

        <section class="navigation">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <nav class="navbar-expand-lg nav">
                  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <svg class="ham hamRotate ham1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="80" onclick="this.classList.toggle('active')">
                     <path
                           class="line top"
                           d="m 30,33 h 40 c 0,0 9.044436,-0.654587 9.044436,-8.508902 0,-7.854315 -8.024349,-11.958003 -14.89975,-10.85914 -6.875401,1.098863 -13.637059,4.171617 -13.637059,16.368042 v 40" />
                     <path
                           class="line middle"
                           d="m 30,50 h 40" />
                     <path
                           class="line bottom"
                           d="m 30,67 h 40 c 12.796276,0 15.357889,-11.717785 15.357889,-26.851538 0,-15.133752 -4.786586,-27.274118 -16.667516,-27.274118 -11.88093,0 -18.499247,6.994427 -18.435284,17.125656 l 0.252538,40" />
                    </svg>
                   </button>
                  <div class="row collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">
                      <ul>
                        <li><a class="intern hvr-wobble-bottom" href="news.html">News</a></li>
                        <li><a class="intern hvr-wobble-bottom" href="tickets.html">Tickets</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">
                      <ul>
                        <li><a class="active intern hvr-wobble-bottom" href="info.html">Info</a></li>
                        <li><a class="intern hvr-wobble-bottom" href="throwback.html">Rückblick</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </nav>
              </div>
          </div>
        </section>


<section class="main-content info">

              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <h1>PULS Open Air</h1>
                  <p>Pulsierende Kugeln und glühende Dreiecke, ein traumhaftes Schlossgelände - und über allem schwebt der Sound von Acts aus Bayern, Deutschland und der Welt. Das PULS Open Air ist der perfekte Ort zum Musikentdecken. Gemeinsam mit Freunden und einer offenen Community, für die ausgelassenes Feiern und eine nachhaltige Lebensweise kein Widerspruch ist. Bei mitreißenden Konzerten abdancen und die neue Lieblingsband finden, sich von Live-Podcasts und Workshops inspirieren lassen, gutes Essen und Drinks genießen, über die Welt diskutieren, bis spät in die Nacht feiern, oder einfach in der Hängematte chillen und die Seele baumeln lassen – beim PULS Open Air ist alles möglich.</p>
                  <h1>Was ist PULS?</h1>
                  <p>PULS ist das junge Programm des Bayerischen Rundfunks. Und zwar in echt. Die Musik bei PULS haut gleichermaßen voll drauf wie daneben, glüht vor und randaliert, rummst und gstanzlt. PULS holt alle an den Regler, die auf dem Smartphone "Daumen hoch" und "Daumen runter" machen können. PULS schielt auf die Wahlurne, schleicht in die Moschee und lupft die Bettdecke. PULS mag dieses Internet. Alle Datenkraken dort mag es aber gar nicht, genauso wenig wie alle Internet-Regulierer, -Zensierer oder Vorratsdatenspeicherer. Eure Likes braucht es trotzdem. PULS lacht über Hipster, trägt dabei selbst Bart und Röhrenjeans. PULS pendelt vom Berg nach Brooklyn und weiter ins Bierzelt - zum Hören, zum Schauen und zum Klicken.</p>
                  <div class="space"></div>
                  <h1>FAQ</h1>
                  <div class="accordion faq" id="accordionExample">
                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                          <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                            Wie komme ich zum PULS Open Air?
                          </button>
                        </h5>
                      </div>

                      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <p>Das Schloss Kaltenberg liegt ca. 50 km westlich von München. Der Bahnhof Geltendorf ist mit der Münchner S-Bahn und der Regionalbahn gut zu erreichen.<br><br>
                          Nutzt die Öffentlichen! Wir stellen einen kostenlosen Shuttlebus vom Bahnhof Geltendorf direkt zum Festivalgelände zur Verfügung. Er fährt am Donnerstag von 15:00 – 23:00 Uhr, am Freitag und Samstag von 09:00 – 01:00 Uhr und am Sonntag von 08:00 – 14:00 Uhr.
                          Der Bahnhof Geltendorf ist barrierefrei.<br>
                          Falls ihr mit dem Auto kommt: Es stehen ausreichend Parkplätze zur Verfügung. Für Wohnmobile gibt es einen eigenen Parkplatz. Zelten ist auf den Parkplätzen nicht erlaubt. Für BesucherInnen mit Mobilitätseinschränkung gibt es entsprechend gekennzeichnete Parkplätze direkt am Eingang zum Veranstaltungsgelände.
                          Parken kostet 5 Euro.<br><br>
                          Die genaue Adresse fürs Navi:<br>e
                          Schloßstraße 13, 82269 Geltendorf</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                          <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                            Ab wann kann ich anreisen?
                          </button>
                        </h5>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <p>Der Campingplatz ist am Donnerstagnachmittag ab 16 Uhr geöffnet.<br>
                            Von 20 Uhr bis 02 Uhr feiern wir dort wieder unsere Pre-Party!<br>
                            Am Freitag und Samstag öffnet das Festivalgelände um 12:00 Uhr mittags.</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    

                    

                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header" id="heading8">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                          <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse8" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse8">
                            Wo gibt’s Festivalbändchen?
                          </button>
                        </h5>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse8" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading8" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <p>Bändchen gibt es im Tausch gegen gültige Tickets an der Bändchenausgabe. Dort bekommt ihr Infos zum Festivalprogramm und dem Gelände – damit ihr immer die Orientierung behaltet.
                            <br><br>
                            Wer ohne gültiges Festivalbändchen auf dem Gelände erwischt wird, muss mit einer Anzeige rechnen. Hier verstehen wir ausnahmsweise keinen Spaß. Kauft ein Ticket, holt euch ein schickes Bändchen und feiert ohne Stress!</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header" id="heading9">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                          <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse9" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse9">
                            Kann ich zum Festival, wenn ich noch nicht 18 bin?
                          </button>
                        </h5>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse9" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading9" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <p>Jugendliche über 16 Jahren dürfen sich nach 24:00 Uhr nur mit schriftlicher Erlaubnis ihrer Personensorgeberechtigten im Veranstaltungsgelände aufhalten.
                            Die Erlaubnis muss während der gesamten Dauer des Events vom Jugendlichen mitgeführt werden und bei eventuellen Kontrollen vorgezeigt werden. Mit der schriftlichen Erlaubnis ist jeweils eine Kopie des Personalausweises des Personensorgeberechtigten vorzulegen.
                            Kinder und Jugendliche unter 16 Jahren dürfen sich nur in Begleitung ihrer Personensorgeberechtigten oder mit schriftlicher Erlaubnis ihrer Personensorgeberechtigten und in Begleitung eines Erziehungsbeauftragten im Veranstaltungsgelände aufhalten.
                            Kinder zwischen 7 und 12 Jahre können das Festival mit ihren Eltern oder Personensorgeberechtigten kostenfrei besuchen, wenn diese im Besitz einer gültigen Einlassberechtigung sind und ihren Rechten und Pflichten als Personensorgeberechtigte nachkommen können.
                            Kinder unter sechs Jahren dürfen nicht auf das Veranstaltungsgelände (Bühnengelände) eingelassen werden.
                            <br><br>
                            Download: Feierzettel U16<br>
                            Download: Feierzettel Ü16</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header" id="heading12">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                          <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse12" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse12">
                            Kann ich zehn bereits gekaufte Tickets zu einem Freundeskreis Ticket upgraden?
                          </button>
                        </h5>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse12" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading12" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <p>Ja das ist möglich. Hierzu bitte die Informationen unter „Tickets“ beachten.</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header" id="heading13">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                          <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse13" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse13">
                            Ich habe ein Ticket ohne Camping. Kann ich trotzdem campen?
                          </button>
                        </h5>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse13" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading13" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <p>Ja! Wenn du ein Festivalticket ohne Camping hast, kannst du das upgraden. <br>
                            Benutze dafür bitte dieses Formular und folge den Anweisungen. Kaufe dir dazu bitte einfach das Camping Upgrade unter diesem Link:
                            <a href="https://pulsopenair.reservix.de/p/reservix/event/1308443">Camping Upgrade</a>
                            <br><br>
                            Wenn du ein Tagesticket hast, kannst du ebenfalls das Camping-Upgrade für eine Nacht dazukaufen – sofern auf dem Campingplatz noch genug Platz ist.</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header" id="heading14">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                          <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse14" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse14">
                            Bei meiner Ticketbestellung ist etwas schief gegangen. An wen kann ich mich wenden?
                          </button>
                        </h5>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse14" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading14" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <p>Bitte meldet euch mit Fragen zur Ticketbestellung unter <a href="mailto:tickets@reservix.de">tickets@reservix.de</a> oder telefonisch unter 0761 / 88 788 11</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header" id="heading15">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                          <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse15" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse15">
                            Kann ich mit meinem Wohnmobil kommen?
                          </button>
                        </h5>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse15" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading15" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <p>Ihr habt eine WoMo-Plakette und wollt nochmal sichergehen, dass euer Fahrzeug auf den WoMo-Platz darf? Hier folgt aber noch die Info dazu:<br><br>
                            Wohnmobil: Ein Wohnmobil ist ein Kraftfahrzeug, das entsprechend der Anzahl der Mitreisenden im Fahrzeug feste Schlafplätze und Wohnraum zur Verfügung stellt.<br><br>
                            Wohnwagen: Ein Wohnwagen ist ein auf öffentlichen Straßen zugelassener Anhänger, der, der Anzahl der Mitreisenden im Zugfahrzeug entsprechend, feste Schlafplätze zur Verfügung stellt.<br><br>
                            Nicht zugelassen werden: Ein Neunsitzer mit 9 Reisenden, Kombis wie Passat, Laguna usw. mit mehr als 2 Mitreisenden, VW Polos etc.<br><br>
                            Zugelassen werden: Kombis mit zwei Personen und entsprechenden Einbauten (ggf. auch temporär) PKW mit Wohnwagen, PKW mit Anhänger mit entsprechenden Einbauten (ggf. auch temporär).<br><br>
                            Am Wohnwagen ist EIN Vorzelt oder EINE Pagode erlaubt. Klein- oder Großzelte mit zusätzlichen Schlafgelegenheiten sind nicht erlaubt. Die Security kontrolliert streng auf diese Regel, um das Platzangebot für alle WoMo-Ticketinhaber zu gewährleisten. Es gibt keinen Stromanschluss für Wohnmobile. Stromaggregate sind aus Lärmschutzgründen nicht erlaubt.</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header" id="heading16">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                          <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse16" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse16">
                            Gibt es Duschen auf dem Campingplatz?
                          </button>
                        </h5>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse16" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading16" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <p>Wir werden dafür sorgen, dass immer alle gut riechen – versprochen. Also: Ja, Duschen gibt’s natürlich!</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header" id="heading18">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                          <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse18" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse18">
                            Kann ich als Gastronom auch selbst Essen verkaufen?
                          </button>
                        </h5>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse18" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading18" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <p>Wir haben bereits ein ziemlich ausgeklügeltes Gastronomiekonzept, das fast keine Wünsche offen lässt. Dennoch sind wir offen für neue Ideen und Konzepte. Wenn ihr einen Stand habt oder kennt, der uns definitiv noch fehlt, schreibt uns eine Mail an <a href="mailto:vipo@uferlos-festival.de">vipo@uferlos-festival.de</a>.</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header" id="heading19">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                          <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse19" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse19">
                            Gibt es kostenloses Trinkwasser?
                          </button>
                        </h5>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse19" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading19" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <p>Ja – es gibt Trinkwasser-Stationen auf dem Campingplatz und bei den Bühnen. Nicht vergessen, sie auch zu benutzen! </p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header" id="heading20">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                          <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse20" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse20">
                            Gibt es einen Supermarkt?
                          </button>
                        </h5>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse20" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading20" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <p>Etwa 15 Minuten zu Fuß entfernt findet ihr verschiedene Einkaufsmöglichkeiten. Im Rahmen unseres Gastronomiekonzeptes findet ihr auf dem Festivalgelände ein vielfältiges Angebot an frisch zubereiteten Speisen und Getränken.</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header" id="heading21">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                          <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse21" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse21">
                            Was darf mit auf den Campingplatz und was nicht?
                          </button>
                        </h5>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse21" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading21" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <p>Gegenstände, die man anderen vehement an den Kopf hauen kann, bleiben draußen. Getränke in Glasflaschen und -behältern sind wegen der Verletzungsgefahr auf dem gesamten Gelände nicht erlaubt.<br>
                            Aus Sicherheitsgründen sind Gaskocher, Autobatterien, Trockenbatterien, Trockeneis u.ä. auf dem kompletten Gelände verboten. Als Alternative empfehlen wir Esbit-Kocher mit Trockenbrennstoff.<br>
                            Standgrills sind erlaubt. Aber Obacht: Wir befinden uns hier auf einer blühenden Wiese und es kann auch ziemlich heiß werden, deshalb:<br><br>
                            Bitte schüttet die Kohle nicht in die Wiese!<br>
                            Lasst die Glut ausglimmen, löscht ggf. mit Wasser und gebt sie in euren Müllsack!<br>
                            Aus Lärmschutzgründen ist die Mitnahme von Stromaggregaten nicht gestattet.<br>
                            Waffen und Pyrotechnik sind verbotener als verboten.</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header" id="heading22">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                          <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse22" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse22">
                            Was darf mit aufs Festivalgelände und was nicht?
                          </button>
                        </h5>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse22" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading22" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <p>Alles, was auf dem Campingplatz nicht geht (siehe oben), geht auf dem Festivalgelände natürlich auch nicht. Außerdem dürft ihr keine Getränke und Lebensmittel rein nehmen.<br>
                            Taschen: Gerade viele Tagesbesucher werden eventuell größere Taschen mitnehmen – aus Sicherheitsgründen können wir das dieses Jahr leider nicht zulassen. Alle großen Taschen, Wanderrucksäcke, etc sind auf dem Veranstaltungsgelände verboten. Bitte nehmt stattdessen Gürteltasche, kleine Umhängetasche oder Stoffturnbeutel mit. Orientiert euch bei der Auswahl eurer Tasche für den Tag an 25 cm x 25 cm Größe. Alles drüber wird eher schwierig.</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header" id="heading23">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                          <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse23" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse23">
                          Kann mein Hund mit?
                          </button>
                        </h5>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse23" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading23" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <p>Nein. Das Mitbringen von Tieren ist generell verboten. Das gilt natürlich nicht für nachweislich ausgebildete Blindenhunde!</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header" id="heading27">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                          <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse27" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse27">
                            Gibt es besondere Angebote für Menschen mit Behinderung?
                          </button>
                        </h5>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse27" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading27" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <p>Die Begleitung eines Menschen mit Behinderung hat freien Eintritt (Behindertenausweis mit dem Vermerk “B” erforderlich), der Bahnhof Geltendorf ist barrierefrei und es gibt entsprechend gekennzeichnete Parkplätze direkt am Eingang.
                            Für die Bänderausgabe und alle weiteren Fragen und Anliegen meldet euch bitte direkt an der Kasse. Da das Bänderzelt mit dem Split für Rollis nicht ausreichend gut erreichbar ist, unterstützen wir euch jederzeit gerne für einen reibungslosen Einlass.
                            Für RollstuhlfahrerInnen und ihre Begleitung steht ein überdachter Bereich mit direktem Blick auf die Kugelbühne (Hauptbühne) und ein Podest mit Blick auf die Pyramidenbühne (Nebenbühne) zur Verfügung. 
                            Auf dem Veranstaltungsgelände gibt es behindertengerechte Toiletten. Zusätzlich stehen auf dem Campingplatz barrierefreie Sanitäranlagen zur Verfügung.<br><br>
                            Bei Unklarheiten bezüglich der Barrierefreiheit könnt ihr uns vorab mailen an <a href="mailto:info@amont-gastro.de">info@amont-gastro.de</a>.<br>
                            Wir geben unser Bestes, dass unser PULS Open Air ein Festival für alle wird. Sollten euch dennoch unbequeme Hürden und Situationen auffallen, dann zögert nicht euch vor Ort an unser Team zu wenden.
                             </p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Hope it helps. :-)